# Android.Write file to sdcard

Tags: android-sdcard

I know this question was asked hundred times but for some reason accepted answers don't work for me.
I can write to device internal memory with this code:

```
    File root = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    root = new File(root, DATA_FOLDER);
    if (!root.exists())
        root.mkdir();
    File pack = new File(root, "pack???");
    if (!pack.exists())
        pack.mkdir();
    File progress = new File(pack, "save.dat");
    try {
        progress.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   //write file goes here
```

I can see folder structure in the app's folder
However if I change root to

```
File root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

no folders on the sdcard are created.Also I tried with this code:

```
  File progress = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
    if (!progress.exists()) {
        progress.mkdir();
    }
```

No success as well.
Manifest contains permission
`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

UPD:Actually the last code does create new folder but this folder is in internal memory while I need it to be on sdcard